# Incrementing values in loop acting weird - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a code that checks indexes of array with some ID's, and increases some order value for items with those ID's. The code looks something like this:

```
function changeOrder(initialIndex, newIndex, itemsMap, itemIds) {
  const requestPayload = [];
  itemsMap[itemIds[initialIndex]].order = itemsMap[itemIds[newIndex]].order;
  requestPayload.push(itemsMap[itemIds[initialIndex]]);

  if (initialIndex > newIndex) {
     for (let i = newIndex; i < initialIndex; i++) {
         itemsMap[itemIds[i]].order++;
         requestPayload.push(itemsMap[itemIds[i]]);
      }
  }
  console.log(requestPayload);
  return requestPayload;
}
```

Now, the issue is when i hover over the `requestPayload` inside the `console.log`, order values are correct (0, 1, 2 in my case). But once it does the logging, or returns the requestPayload, values are 1, 2, 3. Function is triggered only once, so it doesn't increment them again. Here is the screenshot, you can see when I manually log the values when breakpoint is set vs logged payload.

[image]

EDIT: Solved with the help from @Pointy in the comments:

```
for (let i = newIndex; i < initialIndex; i++) {
         const copy = { ...itemsMap[itemIds[i]] };
         copy.order++;
         requestPayload.push(copy);
      }
```

Comment: Probably your `itemsMap` contains the same "item" object more than once.

Comment: @Pointy nop, it has only those 3 elements, and values are changed correctly, problem occurs after any action like log/return

Comment: What I mean is that if you `.push()` one of those items into an array, you do **not** get a copy of the item. Other than that, without seeing more about where that map  comes from and how it's built, it's hard to say.

Comment: @Pointy map is an object, key is ID , value is object with order field. and itemIds is an array with keys from the map

Comment: Right, I see that much. So you understand that when you pass one of those objects into an array with `.push()`, you do not get a **copy** of the object. That's an extremely common mistake in Stack Overflow questions.

Comment: @Pointy Actually yeah, I got it now, that was the issue